# How to disable the Input Pane of TextBox in UWP mobile app?

Tags: textbox, uwp

There are TextBox and custom keyboard. I need to disable the input pane when TextBox has to get focus. I tried the TryHide method for show and focus events.

```
InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryHide();
```

But it is a very bad worked solution because InputPane is blinking when a user is taping on TextBox. Then I found a possibility of changing input policy in documentation [CoreText​Input​Pane​Display​Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.core.coretextinputpanedisplaypolicy) But the documentation does not explain how to apply this policy. 
Using TextBlock is not suitable for me because I need to manipulate with the cursor and select text. Is there a nice solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has code sample demonstrated [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CustomEditControl/cs/CustomEditControl.xaml.cs).

```
        // Create a CoreTextEditContext for our custom edit control.
        CoreTextServicesManager manager = CoreTextServicesManager.GetForCurrentView();
        _editContext = manager.CreateEditContext();

        // Get the Input Pane so we can programmatically hide and show it.
        _inputPane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();

        // For demonstration purposes, this sample sets the Input Pane display policy to Manual
        // so that it can manually show the software keyboard when the control gains focus and
        // dismiss it when the control loses focus. If you leave the policy as Automatic, then
        // the system will hide and show the Input Pane for you. Note that on Desktop, you will
        // need to implement the UIA text pattern to get expected automatic behavior.
        _editContext.InputPaneDisplayPolicy = CoreTextInputPaneDisplayPolicy.Manual;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But It's need for implementation a new textbox control and this sample show control with less functionality than built-in textbox. I had tried to implement inheritance of textbox and add your code in constructor, but it's do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting the same problem in a WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK) application.

I've managed to solve it with the code below. It should work for UWP as well. It completely prevents the keyboard from showing, without blinking/flickering.

```
public sealed partial class CustomTextBox
{

    private void CustomTextBox_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CoreInputView.GetForCurrentView().PrimaryViewShowing += BlockOnScreenKeyboard;
    }

    private void CustomTextBox_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CoreInputView.GetForCurrentView().PrimaryViewShowing -= BlockOnScreenKeyboard;
    }

    private static void BlockOnScreenKeyboard(CoreInputView sender, CoreInputViewShowingEventArgs args)
    {
        args.TryCancel(); 
        sender.TryHide();
    }

    ...
}
```

`args.TryCancel()` does the job alone but when the app loses focus, the keyboard appears, so `sender.TryHide()` is needed to eliminate this bad-looking behavior.